# Click not working on a button that is dynamically created in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

The overall issue is my dynamically created button wont call the Get_ID method.

I have a form which is designed to add new locations into a stored procedure, what will happen is a postcode is entered into a text field, the user will then click the search button, the search will create a table that will display the postcode, the suburb and a button that will allow the user to add the location into another stored procedure(Database).

```
            <div class="col-12">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Postcode</th>
                            <th>Location Name</th>
                            <th>Add</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tablebody" runat="server">

                    </tbody>

                </table>    
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <asp:Button ID="btn_search" OnClick="Search_Service_Areas" Text="Search" runat="server" CssClass="w-100 btn btn-secondary" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">

            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <asp:Button ID="btn_close" OnClick="Close_Search_Area" Text="Close" runat="server" CssClass="w-100 btn btn-secondary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the HTML in the .aspx page that displays the button.
When the button is clicked the table is filled in.

```
protected void Search_Service_Areas(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<ServiceArea> postcodeslist = new List<ServiceArea>();

            string _tmp = post_code.Text.TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' });

            postcodeslist = saa.PullPostCodeData(_tmp);
            foreach (ServiceArea item in postcodeslist)
            {
                Button buttonAdd = new Button();
                buttonAdd.ID = item.ID;
                buttonAdd.Text = "+";
                buttonAdd.Click += new EventHandler(Get_ID);

                TableRow _tr = new TableRow();
                TableCell _tc1 = new TableCell();
                TableCell _tc2 = new TableCell();
                TableCell _tc3 = new TableCell();

                _tc1.Text = item.PostCode;
                _tc2.Text = item.Suburb;
                _tc3.Controls.Add(buttonAdd);

                _tr.Cells.Add(_tc1);
                _tr.Cells.Add(_tc2);
                _tr.Cells.Add(_tc3);

                tablebody.Controls.Add(_tr);
            }
        }

protected void Get_ID(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Clicked ID");
        }
```

The above code is the C# code behind the .aspx page, its just a method that is fired when the search button is click, it displays all the info in a table including the button but the Click on this dynamically generated button wont fire the Get_ID method and I'm not sure why..

Please help, I suspect it something to do with PostBack but I'm not really sure.
Thanks

Comment: Is your html generated correctly? Have you checked it? Sometimes dynamic html have some syntax error. Check it in browser rather than code

Comment: You will need to recreate those buttons on every postback

Comment: Yeah checked the browser and it displays a button, with an ID, but will it show has a Click in the inspector?

Comment: I suggest you have a read of: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8114/Dynamically-Created-Controls-in-ASP-NET

Comment: How do I do that @HansKeﬆing ?

Comment: Using grid view is better idea to display data in tabular structure.